# iOS change app language objective c is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iOS application with objective c. When i try to change language , it not take effect without close and reopen it again, any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have some code to show your problem?

Comment: i don't have error code, but after i change language in app it  not take effect, and if a close app and reopen it again the language has changed. i want to change language automatically after button click.

this app i have develop in android and language change is working good. its not necessary to close and reopen it.

Comment: Are you using Localized files/strings?

Comment: yes but its not take effect without reopen it

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial: [Internationalisation in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014). Its not as easy as just changing the language in your phone.